# Is it possible to implement ASN.1 DER in Rust using Serde?

Tags: rust, asn.1, serde

AFAIK there's no (flexible and stable) ASN.1 {ser,deser}ialization library in Rust, so I'm looking into making one (while learning Rust at the same time). My goal is SNMP (v1-v3) client implementation in Rust.

Before starting from scratch, I'd like to ask Serde team or experienced Serde users if it's possible to implement ASN.1 codec with Serde. Problem is every object in ASN.1 has it's own header (`TAG` + `LENGTH`), where `TAG` is user defined for each type, so iXX or uXX or bytes or whatever can be any `TAG`.

An ASN.1 object is composed of `tag`, `length` and `payload`. ASN.1 has a set of universal (default) tags for integers, floats, bytestrings (as well as ASCII strings) etc. I could just stick to universal tags for primitive types, but for non-primitive types (tuples, newtypes, structs etc) the type should have an  implementation of the `Asn1Info` trait, providing tag and custom serialize / deserialize functionality.

{ser,deser}ialization of primitive types is trivial, but how can I implement it for complex structures (or newtypes)? They *must* be `Asn1Info`.

I've looked into the [asn1-cereal](https://github.com/keeperofdakeys/asn1-rs) library. It looks like a decent ASN.1 implementation, providing useful macros and stuff. I might as well work on it instead of writing everything from scratch.

Let's assume `tag` is `u8` and Asn1Info trait looks like this:

```
pub trait Asn1Info {
  fn asn1_tag() -> u8;
}
```

Then I have a newtype like `pub struct Counter(u32)` with it's own application-specific tag. I'd then make an impl for Counter like this:

```
impl Asn1Info for Counter {
    fn asn1_tag() -> u8 {
        0x41
    }
}
```

Now how do I serialize it with tag `0x41` without manually implementing `Serialize` trait? There's no way to inject additional information to `Serializer`, so I'm unable to reuse all non-primitive serialization methods in it (like `serialize_newtype_variant`).
If I can't use `Serializer` methods in `Serialize` trait impl for custom ASN.1 objects (application-specific, context-specific etc.), then there's no way (or no point) to implement a useful ASN.1 codec with Serde, isn't it?

Comment: I think it's perfectly possible to implement an an ASN.1 codec with serde. But you need to choose a specific format (BER, DER, ...) and you probably can share only little code between the formats.

Comment: The [official documentation](https://serde.rs/data-format.html) has a section on developing your own formats, in which you are advised to understand the [Serde data model](https://serde.rs/data-model.html). Can you make your question more specific on the matter that is troubling you?

Comment: @E_net4, now there should be enough information on the issue. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: You seem to depend too much on a trait rather than the structs. Would there still be a problem if you focused on implementing `Serialize` to each complex type?

Comment: @oli_obk : You can share a fuckton of code, the main difference between DER (CER) and BER is that BER allows for streaming (unknown-length structures, which use end marker instead of size), while DER (CER) require the size be known in advance. It's like 2-4 pages in Dubuisson's book (free; http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/books-whitepapers-pubs/dubuisson-asn1-book.PDF). Now, PER and XER are certainly "more fun" ;-)

Comment: @MiloslavRaus, there's uPER, cannonical PER, and JSON too for good measure! BTW, leveraging Serde will be code first, whereas a lot of ASN.1 usage is schema first, with a schema compiler producing source code in C, C++, or whatever. I'm looking forward to the hallowed day we get that for Rust!